# Select distinct value when count = 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, select, group-by, having-clause

I have a table that looks like this

```
fID_a    fID_b
1        1
1        2
2        2
3        1
```

I want all `fID_a` where `fID_b` is 1 AND where `fID_a` is a single record in that table.

I have a sql query that looks like this

```
select fID_a from tbl 
 where fID_b = 1 
 group by fID_a 
having count(*) = 1
```

But that query still includes the `fID_a` 1 even though there are 2 records in that table!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT fID_a FROM tbl
GROUP BY fID_a 
HAVING MAX(fID_b)=1
AND MIN(fID_b)=1
```

Comment: OP needs single record so lower than 1 value does not make any difference [**see here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67e29/2)

Comment: +1 +1 +1. Most efficient as it will do no counting, only simple seeks on the `(fid_a, fid_b)` index. (@Markus : add this index!)

Comment: its easier to add more fID_b numbers

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `where` clause then you would filter out other values what would make the `count` inaccurate.

```
select fID_a 
from tbl  
group by fID_a 
having count(*) = 1 
and sum(case when fID_b = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `case` there.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Why? No DB engine is specified. MySQL would not need a case, but MSSQL would.

Comment: I think `having count(*) = 1 and sum(fID_b) = 1` would be enough. Is there anything in MSSQL that would make it fail?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: What if there are `fID_b` being `0`?

Comment: @juergend Marcin is right. His condition would be fine, too, (and shorter but I doubt it would be more efficient.)

Answer (score 2):

You should try-self join to achieve this:

```
SELECT t1.fID_a 
  FROM tbl t1
  JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.fid_a = t2.fid_a
   AND t1.fid_b = 1
 GROUP BY t1.fID_a 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

- See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e8b7/5)
- See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60359/2) with more values:

Comment: Self join does not make any sense.

Comment: @Tarik yet it returns the wanted results - while your query doesn't.

Comment: @Tarik - Self join is used to remove the condition `WHERE fid_b = 1`. Because if we use `WHERE fid_b = 1` directly, [it will take fid_a = 1 and fid_a = 6 as well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60359/9). By using `JOIN` we can get exact count with condition [WHERE fid_b = 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60359/10).

Answer (score 0):

```
select fID_a,fID_b 
from tb1, (select fID_a 
             from tb1 
         group by fID_a 
           having count(*) = 1) temp
where tb1.fID_a = temp.fID_a
and fID_b = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. Your query does not work beacuse mysql computes where clause before having clause.

```
select fID_a from 
       (select fID_a, fID_b 
        from tbl 
        group by fID_a 
        having count(*) = 1) temp 
where fID_b = 1
```

Comment: Just tested it on SQL server and I got two rows with fID_a = 2 and fID_a = 3

Comment: @Tarik I also tested it on mysql server and I got only one row with fID_a = 3

Comment: Oops, commented on the wrong answer. Sorry. Tested on SQL Server I got: Column 'tbl.fID_b' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Tarik My query does not work on MS SQL Server but it works on mysql server.

Comment: @dijkstra No it doesn't. It will occasionally work in MySQL. But it will fail with strict ANSI settings. And I don't see a MySQL tag in the question.